# How to capture value from ng-model in td

Tags: html, angularjs

i have HTML table contains ng-repeat that loops on a list of data coming from an API , the problem is i want to use the same list to update data then send it back to the API. But when i console the `ng-model` inside the `td` i got `undefined`,
any idea how to capture the value of input box inside a td by ng-model

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </th>
      <th style="width: 60%;">
        Sub Service
      </th>
      <th>
        Payment
      </th>
      <th>
        Insure
      </th>
      <th>
        Cash
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="s in subServices">
      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="s.details" />
      </td>
      <td>
        {{s.SUBSERVNAME_L}}
      </td>
      <td>
        <select ng-model="pay">
          <option value="0">Choose</option>
          <option ng-repeat="p in payTypes" value="{{p.payid}}" ng-selected="{{p.payid == pay}}">{{p.paynm}}</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="insure" class="form-control input-sm" type="number" ng-model="insure" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control input-sm" type="number" ng-model="cash" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

any idea how to capture value of `ng-model="pay"` , `ng-model="insure"` and `ng-model="cash"`

Thanks in advance

sending data to API code

```
$scope.subSrvData = [];
        $scope.save = function () {

            console.log($scope.insure);

            $scope.subServices.forEach(function (s) {
                if (s.details == true) {
                    console.log(s);
                    $scope.subSrvData.push({ Main_Serv: $scope.mainSrv, Sub_Serv: s.SUB_SERV, InsuredAmt: $scope.insure, CashAmt: $scope.cash, Perc_Amt: $scope.pay})
                }
            })

            console.log($scope.subSrvData);


            var promisepost = NetRevenueSetupSrv.deleteSubs("NetRevenueSetup/deleteSubs?mainSrv=" + $scope.mainSrv);
                promisepost.then(function (response) {
                    var _response = response.data;
                    if (_response.Value == -1) {
                        toastr['error'](_response.Message);
                        return;
                    }
                    var promisepost = NetRevenueSetupSrv.save("NetRevenueSetup/save", $scope.subSrvData);
                    promisepost.then(function (response) {
                        var _response = response.data;
                        if (_response.Value == -1) {
                            toastr['error'](_response.Message);
                            return;
                        }
                        toastr.success("Successfully Saved");
                        

                    })
                    $scope.subSrvData = [];
                })
                
            

        }
```

Comment: can you show the code where you are trying to send values back to the API ?

Comment: i updated the question , kindly check it

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure these value such as "pay","insure","cash" are declared in the components typescript file.

Html:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
    <option *ngFor="let o of options">
    {{o.name}}
    </option>
</select>

<button (click)="print()">Click me</button>

<p>Selected option: {{ selectedOption }}</p>
<p>Button output: {{ printedOption }}</p>
```

Typescript:

```
export class AppComponent {
    selectedOption: string;
    printedOption: string;

    options = [
     { name: "option1", value: 1 },
     { name: "option2", value: 2 }
    ]
    print() {
      this.printedOption = this.selectedOption;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, but i am using Angularjs not modern Angular